# How to create serverless image processing with Google Function and Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

On AWS I use it with S3 + Lambda combination. As new image uploaded to a bucket, lambda is triggered and create 3 different sizes of image (small, medium, large). How can I do this with GCS + Function?

PS: I know that there's "getImageServingUrl()", but can this be used with GCE or it's for app engine only?

Would really appreciate any input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Functions directly supports triggers for new objects being uploaded to GCS: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage

For finer control, you can also configure a GCS bucket to publish object upload notifications to a Cloud Pub/Sub topic, and then set a subscription on that topic to trigger Google Cloud Functions: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub

Note that there are some quotas on Cloud Functions uploading and downloading resources, so if you need to process more than to 1 Gigabyte of image data per 100 seconds or so, you may need to request a quota increase: https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas

Comment: Thanks for the help Brandon. For 2nd paragraph, how can I use pub/sub with my case? The goal is simply to make 1 image that uploaded by user into 3 different images automatically. The original uploaded image will go into the buckets, and function will generate 3 separates image dimension from it.